# ngx-charts vertical bar 2d (grouped) bar groups pushed at sides

Tags: ngx-charts

I'm having some pain in the a** with ngx-charts vertical bar 2d (grouped bars), bars container width in each group seems to not expand to all width of the group, I've recreated prblem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hznzk9), this might be just a simple problem but im not seeing it, please help :=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you call different elements on the x-Scale for the two objects. Ngx-Charts expects data with the same names in every element on the x-Scale. Your chart thinks every object (croatia, sweden) has the combined length of every possible name in one of them, thats why sweden is on the right and croatia on the left. You can test that if you fill your data with wildcarts like "1","2" etc..

I dont know how to solve this problem with a groupedbarchart, i would recommend using a normal barchart with combined values and show somewhere else what belongs to each value.

Comment: @Boris Pancisek did it help you? Or do you have another solution that you can maybe share with us ?

Comment: Hi lad, sorry for this very long response time, yet thank you for your response. I did not manage to get an solution for this, unfortunatley, it seems that none has it neither. I've started looking for an alternative replacement for ngx-charts as I'd reather use chart out-of-box without going for mix-n-match. If by any means I'm to get solution for this one i'll share it here.